# Varnish Redirection

Tags: http, url, redirect, varnish

Recently I moved to a new system based on Java from PHP platform. The new website has pretty URLs such as -

http://mysite.com/science/2013/03/22/universe-is-older-than-previously-thought

The old website had URLs like -mysite.com/details.php?cid=37&id=239411

For search engine results we need to redirect all these URLs containing */details.php?* to the homepage, say urlredirect.com. I have been looking at these examples https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleRedirectInVCL and came up with the following in redirect.vcl of my Varnish configuration.

In vcl_recv function -

```
 if(req.url~ "^/details.php?$" ) {
 error 301 "Moved Temporarily";
  }
```

But I am confused what should be there in vcl_error function? For now it is like this -

```
  else if(obj.status == 301 && req.url~ "^/details.php?$"){
    set obj.http.Location = "http://bdnews24.com";
    return (deliver);
  }
```

I think it's simple as that? still it would be great to share experience with someone who has done this.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to do this in Varnish 4.0, the way to do it have changed a bit

```
#default.vcl

sub vcl_recv {
  if (req.req.url~ "^/details.php?$") {
    return (synth (750, "")); #This throws a synthetic page so the request won't go to the backend
  }
}

sub vcl_synth {
  if (resp.status == 750) {
    set resp.status = 301;
    set resp.http.Location = "http://bdnews24.com";
    return(deliver);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It would be better to create a custom error code and then send the redirect URL there instead of having to repeat yourself in your vcl_error. A short example:

In vcl_recv:

```
set req.http.x-Redir-Url = "http://newdomain.com" + req.url; 
error 750 req.http.x-Redir-Url;
```

In vcl_error:

```
if (obj.status == 750) {
    set obj.http.Location = obj.response;
    set obj.status = 301;
    return(deliver);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes it's safer to do it this way.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work in varnish 4! - see the other answer.